# Chrome deja de hacer request a localhost

Tags: jquery, django, windows, apache, chrome

Estoy teniendo un problema rarisimo con un sitio en Django, corriendo sobre apache en un windows 7 32 bits.

El sitio siempre corre en localhost mediante chrome en modo kiosko pero posee conexión a internet mediante una wifi.

El problema es que, las páginas poseen botones los cuales tienen asociado el evento onclick="window.location.href='{% url "nombre_url" %}'" las cuales funcionan correctamente, cuando el usuario hace clic redirecciona a la página correcta, pero por alguna razón dejan de funcionar.

Los botones también tienen asociado un jquery cuando se clickean que los deshabilita y muestra un gif estilo loading. Siempre que se "tilda" el sitio esta mostrando la imagen de loading con los botones deshabilitados.

Revise los logs de apache y del sitio pero no hay ningún error, es como si chrome de repente no hace el request al servidor web.

Ya probé configurar el chrome para que no utilice proxy, deshabilitar ipv6 (habia algunos errores en el windows event log) pero nada lo soluciona. Lo mas extraño es que la misma PC donde esta instalado el sitio funciona correctamente y el error solo se da cuando se conecta a un wifi pero no podemos encontrar que problema le puede estar ocasionando.

¿Alguna idea de que podría estar mal o que otra cosa podría verificar para reproducir y evitar este problema?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

quiza puede parecer muy basico, pero revisaste si el famoso firewall de windows esta bloqueando algo? deshabilitalo y prueba.
otra cosa podria ser que tengas algo en htaccess bloqueando solicitudes.
probaste con otro navegador? hay algun dispositivo en tu red que quiza este bloqueando algo (router, AP, FW).
Si haces ping, llegas al server?

Comment: Hola! No tiene el archivo .htaccess el sitio. No probé aún usar otro navegador ni deshabilitar el firewall, lo pruebo y te digo. Igualmente, lo extraño es que solamente sucede este problema cuando esta conectado a esa red wifi, seguramente también probaré correr el sitio sin que este conectada a la red. Además, una vez que encontré "tildado" el sitio, apreté F12 (abrí las herramientas de desarrollo de chrome) y automáticamente se "destildo" y se redirigió a la pagina que tenía que ir.